# Projections of uniform random variable are independent

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Given a region $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with finite area. Let $\xi$ be a uniform random variable representing the points in $D$. So $\xi$ gives rise to two random variables - its coordinates $\xi_x$ and $\xi_y$. If those two random variables are independent, what can we say about the region $D$.

We suspect that $D$ must be a rectangle. We also suspect that more constraints should be imposed on $D$, so that the proof be easier (or at least exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ the the supports of the distributions of your two projected coordinates: $\xi_X$ and $\xi_Y.$  Then I think it is pretty clear that $D=A\times B$.  In the sense that only for such $D$ will $\xi_X$ and $\xi_Y$ be independent, in which case $\xi_X$ will be uniformly distributed on $A$, and so on, and conversely, given any two sets $A$ and $B$ of equal finite Lebesgue measure, one can take $D=A\times B$ and project, and so on.